# Best way to classify a set through a single feature?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, regression, linear-regression, logistic-regression

I need to classify a single dataset through a numeric value. I added below samples from dataset to explain what my need.

Restriction: Category has two values: `0` or `1`

The question is **"What is the best `T` score to classify new records through `T` score"**.

**Sample data:**

```
-------------------------------
App     Category       T score
-------------------------------
X       1              180
Y       1              75
Z       0              220
A       0              120
B       1              180
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there any restriction on the form of the classifier? Ie. should it be just a threshold or an arbitrary classifier?

- If the answer is "threshold"

You simply check **all** possible values of the threshold. In 1D case it is a cheap approach and guarantees a good results (as you actually search through the whole hypothesis space).

- Classifier is arbitrary

There is no definite answer, even for the 1D case. Although, for such simple data the best option is to... draw your data. Use a histogram or kernel density estimation and **see** how does it look like. There is a great chance that you can figure out the exact rules by hand. Otherwise, almost any classifier should be good enough. SVM with RBF kernel should be as good as simple density based approach/KNN.

Comment: I'm working on a scientific paper, so I need to identify this threshold value using an algorithm. Otherwise I developed my own user interface to see success ratios according to different thresholds. I can identify threshold that fits best to classify the data.

Comment: you seem to miss the point here. I'm suggesting a simple algorithm, which chekcs each threshold and selects the best one. This is exactly what learning algorithms do. They search for such parameters which minimize the error (empirical error in this particular case). There is no qualitative difference between such an approach and any other.